# Keyboard interrupt stops working after a while

Tags: command-line, 16.04, interrupts

Sometimes, after a while running processes and different commands in a terminal tab, the tab stops reacting to Ctrl+C. It simply prints `^C` but does not interrupt.

Other tabs do handle interrupt properly for the same commands.

The problem exists even for simplest commands, such as `sleep 10`.

What could cause this, and how can I prevent this behaviour ?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Terminal: Terminator
Shell: zsh

Comment: Try another terminal emulator and try the tty so Terminator can be eliminated as cause of the issue. try bash so that zsh can be eliminated as cause.

Comment: I'll try, but the problem happens randomly after several hours of usage, so it will be hard to reproduce..